# How to move some revisions from one branch to another?

Tags: mercurial

`hg convert --branchmap` allows moving all revisions in a branch to a different branch. In a branch with multiple heads (e.g. one path leads to a "closed branch") how do I move some of the revisions to a different branch while leaving others unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Pierre-Yves David](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5382)

> You should be able to achieve this using "histedit". Use the "edit" action on the first changesets and set up branch name before committing.

So for example, say we have:

```
@  changeset:   3:acd042300874
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        user@name.com
|  date:        Tue Sep 27 11:22:33 2016 -0400
|  summary:     commit4
|
o  changeset:   2:6cd4bf5a3e25
|  parent:      0:7f1fbf9d8623
|  user:        user@name.com
|  date:        Tue Sep 27 11:22:33 2016 -0400
|  summary:     commit3
|
| o  changeset:   1:5cf7adbb92ea
|/   user:        user@name.com
|    date:        Tue Sep 27 11:22:32 2016 -0400
|    summary:     commit2
|
o  changeset:   0:7f1fbf9d8623
   user:        user@name.com
   date:        Tue Sep 27 11:22:32 2016 -0400
   summary:     commit1
```

and we want to move revisions 2, 3 onto a different branch we would do the following:

1. hg update 3
2. hg histedit 2
3. Change both revisions from "pick" to "edit"
4. hg branch "new-branch"
5. hg commit -m "old commit message for rev2"
6. hg histedit --continue
7. hg commit -m "old commit message for rev3"
8. hg histedit --continue

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `branchmap` and `splicemap` options to `hg convert`. Possibly in more than one step, depending on exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did it until I heard of [Pierre's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39728971/14731) answer.